# perl, javascript - how to backescape any special characters printing in perl into javascript

Tags: javascript, perl

how can i backescape any special characters in perl  that i'm printing for javascript coding (ie $asdf, $asdf1, $asdf2, $asdf3, $KEY_ID)?

```
if ($USER_GROUPS_OKAY == 1)
{
    print qq|
    <script>
        var params = \$("#USER_INPUT_FORM").serializeArray();
        params.push({ name: 'menu_mode', value: 'VIEW_IV' });
        params.push({ name: 'KEY_ID_VALID', value: '$KEY_ID' });
        params.push({ name: 'SOURCE_P_NAME', value: '$asdf' });
        params.push({ name: 'DESTINATION_P_NAME', value: '$asdf1' });
        params.push({ name: 'SOURCE_D_NAME', value: '$asdf2' });
        params.push({ name: 'DESTINATION_D_NAME', value: '$asdf3' });                     
        \$.get("cgi_scripts/$0",params,function(data){\$("#graphs").html(data)});
    </script>
|;
}
```

Note: $asdf, $asdf1, $asdf2, $asdf3 are perl variables - if $asdf is defined = qq|'helo world % &%^&*^ '|, this might kill the code

Comment: Could you add hidden input fields inside USER_INPUT_FORM?
like `<input type="hidden" name="KEY_ID_VALID" value="$KEY_ID" />`
When you render the HTML form, you would have `$KEY_ID` take its value from your Perl program...  That way you wouldn't have to push all of the values onto the params array.

Comment: Maybe we aren't understanding the question correctly... You are already escaping special characters in your code - every jQuery variable you have a backslash in front of the `$`, which is the correct way as @Joel confirms.  It seems you would want the values of your Perl variables to be printed, so you wouldn't want to escape those...  Your code looks like it would work, which makes me thing we are missing something.

Comment: `$asdf1` is not a "special character". `$` is a special character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll never catch everything without rewriting the JSON encoder.  See [`encode_json` in JSON](http://p3rl.org/JSON#encode_json)  (from CPAN).

Answer (score 0):

Inside a double quote (i.e. `"` or `qq`) you can escape with a slash `\` however if that is getting confusing because of other meanings/uses of the slash I would recommend changing the parts of the statement that do not need interpolation into single-quote strings (i.e. `'` or `q`) and join them with the string cat operator "dot" (`.`).

If I read you correctly, the only Perl-side variable you need is `$0`, correct? Further the escaped single dollars are only for Perl's sake so we can remove them inside the single-quotes.

```
if ($USER_GROUPS_OKAY == 1)
{
    print q|
      <script>
        var params = $("#USER_INPUT_FORM").serializeArray();
        params.push({ name: 'menu_mode', value: 'VIEW_IV' });
        params.push({ name: 'KEY_ID_VALID', value: '$KEY_ID' });
        params.push({ name: 'SOURCE_P_NAME', value: '$asdf' });
        params.push({ name: 'DESTINATION_P_NAME', value: '$asdf1' });
        params.push({ name: 'SOURCE_D_NAME', value: '$asdf2' });
        params.push({ name: 'DESTINATION_D_NAME', value: '$asdf3' });                     
        $.get(
    | . qq|
        "cgi_scripts/$0"
    | . q|
        ,params,function(data){$("#graphs").html(data)});
      </script>
    |;
}
```